# Handling of click events in jQuery(For Like and Unlike button)

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

I am trying to create a Like-Unlike system using AJAX and jQuery. The "like" event seems to work properly, but when I want to "unlike" the event is not responding. Any suggestions to solve this problem is appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".like").click(function() { //this part is working
        var item_id = $(this).attr("id");
        var dataString = 'item_id=' + item_id;
        $('a#' + item_id).removeClass('like');
        $('a#' + item_id).html('<img src="images/loader.gif" class="loading" />');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                if (data == 0) {
                    alert('you have liked this quote before');
                } else {
                    $('a#' + item_id).addClass('liked');
                    $('a#' + item_id).html(data);
                }
            }
        });

    });

    $(".liked").click(function() { //this part is not working
        var item_id = $(this).attr("id");
        console.log(item_id);
        var dataString = 'item_id=' + item_id;
        $('a#' + item_id).removeClass('liked');

        $('a#' + item_id).html('<img src="images/loader.gif" class="loading" />');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                if (data == 0) {
                    alert('you have liked this quote before');
                } else {
                    $('a#' + item_id).addClass('like');
                    $('a#' + item_id).html(data);
                }
            }
        });

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(".like")` and `$(".liked")` are retrieved when the document is ready but don't get updated when you add/remove classes from an element.

If you assign a more generic class the vote elements like 'like-toggle' you would be able to do the following:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.like-toggle').click(function(event) {
    if ($(event.target).hasClass('like') {
      // Call your unlike code, replace like with liked.
    } else {
      // Call your like code, replace liked with like.
    }
  });
});
```

This will work because the `like-toggle` class never gets removed from the elements and thus the elements which are present when the document is ready will keep functioning.